# Recursively removing all backslashes in directory and file names with find and rename

Tags: command-line, find, regular-expression, rename

I want to extend a recent question which I have asked to remove french characters with a combination of `find` and `rename`:

[Rename files and directories with French characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535546/rename-files-and-directories-with-french-characters)

Now I am facing some files and directories with a `\` in their names which is not touched by the following command:

```
find . -depth -execdir rename -n '
 utf8::decode$_ or die "cannot decode $_\n";
 s{[^\w.\@+,#!?:&%~()\[\]/\\ -]}{?}gs;
 utf8::encode$_;
 ' {} +
```

I tried to use `\\` to target that name but it seems to be the incorrect way. The file naming I am talking about looks like that:

```
$ls
'Links '

$ls -1b
Links\ *WHITESPACE*
```

Those dir names are causing PHP Code to break. For example when trying to move a file inside a dir with that naming.

How can I enhance the given command to also target the described names?

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258679/why-is-ls-suddenly-wrapping-items-with-spaces-in-single-quotes

Comment: This may ultimately be another case of [why not to parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  If you can post the PHP code that is breaking, and sufficient context around it, someone may be able to guide you in how to make your PHP code more robust.